# Проблема с базой данных и DataTable

Tags: c#, база-данных, datatable

У меня есть база данных и в ней есть 1 запись у которой Login = test123-Login , и Password = test123-Login. Но когда я ввожу Логин test123-Login и пароль 
test123-**l**ogin (здесь l маленькая а в записи большая).

DataBaseHelper.cs

```
public static bool LoginExist(string login, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string clearLogin = login.Trim();
                string clearPassword = password.Trim();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE Login=@clearLogin AND Password=@clearPassword", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("clearLogin", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = clearLogin;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("clearPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = clearPassword;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                return count == 0 ? false : true;
            }
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Ошибка авторизации! Перезапустите приложение.", "Ошибка авторизации", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error); return false; }
    }
```

И когда я ввожу неправильный пароль то мне все равно дает зайти в главное приложение. Как это исправить?

И кто может то подскажите правильно ли я все делаю? И как лучше сделать реализацию авторизации?

Comment: Не очень хорошо хранить в базе не зашифрованный пароль. Храните хэш пароля и уже с ним работайте. не надо будет бояться за регистр или что то еще.

Comment: Это да я над этим буду работать. А разве хэш у test123-Login и у test123-login будет один и тот-же?

Comment: Хотя я сейчас подумал конечно разные хэш и при регистрации конечно будет 1 хэш а при авторизации другой. Все вроде разобрался.

Comment: А в плане кода нормально все?

Comment: А когда у тебя пароль максимальной длины 24 то хэш какой длины будет?

Comment: Зависит от вашего алгоритма хеширования

Comment: Скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на ресурс где я поподробнее почитаю про это. Чтоб не задавать впредь таких вопросов.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков А на что ссылку то, просто найдите алгоритм, который будет получать хэш пароля и как можно меньше передавайте пароль в открытом виде. Вот самый простой пример [Sha1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m4zBSU) - он выдаст пароль в таком виде `2b24873d6f7b4bde86738012c8bed87f2c2e1e20`, вот это вы и сверяете. При малейшем изменении вы получать будете другой хэш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что не указана длина типа `varchar`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("clearLogin", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = clearLogin;
```

Таким образом, длина равна 1.

Размер нужно указать тот же, который у вас в таблице.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("clearLogin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 24).Value = clearLogin;
```

К тому же, возможно, стоит использовать `nvarchar` - это позволит использовать не только английские буквы в логине и пароле (если вас это устраивает).

---

Использование `DataTable` в данном случае совершенно излишне.

Кроме того, следует диспозить (освобождать) все используемые ресурсы.

Давайте перепишем код:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string clearLogin = login.Trim();
    string clearPassword = password.Trim();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE Login=@clearLogin AND Password=@clearPassword",
        connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("clearLogin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 24).Value = clearLogin;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("clearPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 24).Value = clearPassword;

        int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return count != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: в параметрах SqlCommand длину строки можно не указывать. В хранимках указывать обязательно, иначе да, длина будет считаться единицей. И стоит упомянуть про COLLATION, так как первая из обозначенных автором проблем - не различается регистр букв. В остальном согласен.